# Get a random subset of a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, random

I have a very large dictionary, and I want to extract a subsample, on which I then want to iterate. I tried:

```
import random
dictionary = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4, 'e':5}
keys = random.sample(dictionary, 3)
sample = dictionary[keys]
```

But it doesn't work:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[..]/foobar.py", line 4, in <module>
    sample = dictionary[keys]
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

This works:

```
import random
dictionary = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4, 'e':5}
keys = random.sample(dictionary, 3)
sample = {key: dictionary[key] for key in keys}
```

It seems a bit word-ish: I hoped there would be a vectorized way to build the new dictionary. However, is this the right/most Pythonic way to do it? Also, if I want to iterate on this sample, should I do like this:

```
for key, value in sample.iteritems():
    print(key, value)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With

```
dict(random.sample(dictionary.items(), N))
```

you can select `N` random (key, value) pairs from your dictionary and pass them to the `dict` constructor.

Demo:

```
>>> import random
>>> dictionary = dict(enumerate(range(10)))
>>> dictionary
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9}
>>> N = 3
>>> dict(random.sample(dictionary.items(), N))
{3: 3, 6: 6, 9: 9}
```

Comment: This Q&A is a bit old and this now raises `DeprecationWarning: Sampling from a set deprecated since Python 3.9 and will be removed in a subsequent version.` The easiest fix would be to wrap with a `list(...)` call